# Bootstrap Tabdrop not working in MVC cshtml

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, bootstrap-tabs

I have a mvc razor page (cshtml) and i tried to implement the bootstrp tabdrop in it. I am able to get the tabs however the tabdrops are not displayed. When i run the same code in a html file i am able to get the tabs as well as the tabdrop holding my extra tab names. however when i run the code in cshtml file its not getting displayed.

The extra tabs are displayed in the second line and the tabdrop is also not getting displayed.

[Tabdrops Source](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/)

Here is my complete code of my cshtml file in which i have used the tabdrop.js...

```js
<script src="Content/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="Content/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="Content/js/bootstrap-tabdrop.js"></script>
<script src="Content/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
    if (top.location != location) {
        top.location.href = document.location.href;
    }
    $(function () {
        window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
        $('.nav-tabs:first').tabdrop();
        $('.nav-tabs:last').tabdrop({ text: 'More options' });
        $('.nav-pills').tabdrop({ text: 'With pills' });
    });
</script>
```

```css
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap-tabdrop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
        <!-- Right side column. Contains the navbar and content of the page -->
        <aside class="right-side">
            <!-- Main row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Left col -->
                <section class="col-lg-6 connectedSortable">
                    <!-- Box (with bar chart) -->
                    <div id="loading-example">
                        <div class="box-body no-padding">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <section class="content">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-example" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-tab7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-tab8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 8</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-tab1">
                        <p>This is tab 1!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-tab2">
                        <p>This is tab 2!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-tab3">
                        <p>This is tab 3!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-tab4">
                        <p>This is tab 4!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-tab5">
                        <p>This is tab 5!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-tab6">
                        <p>This is tab 6!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-tab7">
                        <p>This is tab 7!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-tab8">
                        <p>This is tab 8!</p>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <!-- top row -->
                <!-- /.row -->
            </section><!-- /.content -->
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the css files stored in the location

> Content\css

and Javascript Files stored in the location

> Content\js

The cshtml file has the bootstrap theme of ADMINLTE bootstrap.

Can any one help me with this? I want to know whether the bootstrap tabdrops works with cshtml file or not?

Comment: Make sure that the bootstrap javascript file is referenced correctly on your razor page.

Comment: Hi Chris, The javscript file is correctly referenced only. When i run the same code in html it works..

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. The tabdrop plugin initialized when window re-size.

I solved it by resizing the window after init tabdrop.

```
$(window).resize();
```

Comment: If you have a question, please use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. Please do not post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. I hope TieminLin has posted an answer that will solve my issue.

Comment: @KarthikVenkatraman OK, I hope it works for you, but TieminLin's initial post was phrased as a question, and did not include any suggestion for a fix. That's what I commented on.

Comment: Well No issues.. Just saying it.. regarding the solution, i didnt try it out as we have removed the tabdrops totally :(